# How to Reference the Row Being Operated on in lapply() in R

Tags: r, function, user-defined-functions, nested-loops, lapply

I need help referencing the observation I'm working on with `lapply()` in a user defined function in R. I would like to see where each observation of a data frame ranks in a subset of similar observations of the same data frame. I'm having trouble referencing the original observation, in order to extract its rank.

Here is a sample of my data:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(MP = c(29L, 32L, 3L, 34L, 14L, 3L, 40L, 17L, 13L, 
14L, 4L, 36L, 6L, 33L, 25L, 12L, 17L, 3L, 15L, 28L, 33L, 39L, 
30L), Player.ID = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 14L, 16L, 21L, 
26L, 30L, 34L, 35L, 42L, 41L, 43L, 46L, 58L, 62L, 79L, 86L, 100L, 
102L, 106L, 107L), .Label = c("abrinal01", "adamsst01", "aldrico01", 
"aldrila01", "anderky01", "anderry01", "antetgi01", "anthoca01", 
"anunoog01", "arthuda01", "bartowi01", "bealbr01", "bertada01", 
"bjeline01", "brogdma01", "brookaa01", "brookdi01", "brownlo01", 
"brownst02", "bullore01", "butleji01", "buyckdw01", "capelca01", 
"chandwi01", "craigto01", "crawfja01", "davisde01", "dellama01", 
"derozde01", "dienggo01", "drumman01", "ennisja01", "farieke01", 
"feltora01", "fergute01", "forbebr01", "fraziti01", "gallola01", 
"gasolma01", "gasolpa01", "georgma01", "georgpa01", "gibsota01", 
"ginobma01", "gortama01", "grantje01", "greenda02", "greenge01", 
"greenja01", "griffbl01", "hardeja01", "harrian01", "harriga01", 
"henrymy01", "hensojo01", "hilarne01", "hillida01", "huestjo01", 
"ibakase01", "johnsst04", "jokicni01", "jonesty01", "kennalu01", 
"kilpase01", "lauvejo01", "lowryky01", "lylestr01", "mahinia01", 
"makerth01", "martija01", "mbahalu01", "mclembe01", "meeksjo01", 
"middlkh01", "millspa02", "moreler01", "morrima02", "mudiaem01", 
"muhamsh01", "munfoxa02", "murrade01", "murraja01", "noguelu01", 
"oubreke01", "parketo01", "pattepa01", "paulbr01", "paulch01", 
"plumlma02", "poeltja01", "porteot01", "powelno01", "reedwi02", 
"satorto01", "scottmi01", "seldewa01", "siakapa01", "smithis01", 
"snellto01", "teaguje01", "tollian01", "townska01", "tuckepj01", 
"valanjo01", "vaughra01", "westbru01", "wiggian01", "wilsodj01", 
"wrighde01"), class = "factor"), Game.ID = structure(c(7L, 7L, 
6L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 
7L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 6L), .Label = c("2018-02-01 * DEN", "2018-02-01 * DET", 
"2018-02-01 * HOU", "2018-02-01 * MEM", "2018-02-01 * MIL", "2018-02-01 * MIN", 
"2018-02-01 * OKC", "2018-02-01 * SAS", "2018-02-01 * TOR", "2018-02-01 * WAS"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("MP", "Player.ID", "Game.ID"
), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 14L, 16L, 21L, 26L, 30L, 34L, 
35L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 46L, 58L, 62L, 79L, 86L, 100L, 102L, 106L, 
107L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have defined the following function:

```
> f1 <- function(col1, df, col2){
+   lapply(col1, function(i){
+     df2 <- df[col1 == i, col2]
+     df3 <- data.frame(cbind(sort(df2, decreasing = TRUE), rownames(data.table(sort(df2, decreasing = TRUE)))))
+     df3
+   })
+   }
> f1(df$Game.ID, df, c('MP'))[1:10]
[[1]]
   X1 X2
1  39  1
2  36  2
3  34  3
4  32  4
5  29  5
6  25  6
7  15  7
8  14  8
9  12  9
10  4 10

[[2]]
   X1 X2
1  39  1
2  36  2
3  34  3
4  32  4
5  29  5
6  25  6
7  15  7
8  14  8
9  12  9
10  4 10

[[3]]
   X1 X2
1  40  1
2  33  2
3  33  3
4  30  4
5  28  5
6  17  6
7  17  7
8  14  8
9  13  9
10  6 10
11  3 11
12  3 12
13  3 13

[[4]]
   X1 X2
1  39  1
2  36  2
3  34  3
4  32  4
5  29  5
6  25  6
7  15  7
8  14  8
9  12  9
10  4 10

[[5]]
   X1 X2
1  40  1
2  33  2
3  33  3
4  30  4
5  28  5
6  17  6
7  17  7
8  14  8
9  13  9
10  6 10
11  3 11
12  3 12
13  3 13

[[6]]
   X1 X2
1  40  1
2  33  2
3  33  3
4  30  4
5  28  5
6  17  6
7  17  7
8  14  8
9  13  9
10  6 10
11  3 11
12  3 12
13  3 13

[[7]]
   X1 X2
1  40  1
2  33  2
3  33  3
4  30  4
5  28  5
6  17  6
7  17  7
8  14  8
9  13  9
10  6 10
11  3 11
12  3 12
13  3 13

[[8]]
   X1 X2
1  40  1
2  33  2
3  33  3
4  30  4
5  28  5
6  17  6
7  17  7
8  14  8
9  13  9
10  6 10
11  3 11
12  3 12
13  3 13

[[9]]
   X1 X2
1  40  1
2  33  2
3  33  3
4  30  4
5  28  5
6  17  6
7  17  7
8  14  8
9  13  9
10  6 10
11  3 11
12  3 12
13  3 13

[[10]]
   X1 X2
1  39  1
2  36  2
3  34  3
4  32  4
5  29  5
6  25  6
7  15  7
8  14  8
9  12  9
10  4 10
```

This function creates a subset, for each observation, of all other observations with an identical `df$Game.ID` and then ranks said observations, in descending order, according to `df$MP`.

I need help extracting the ranking of the observation that corresponds to the one being operated on by `lapply()`. I can reference the ranking by identifying the second column of `df3` in my function:

```
> f1 <- function(col1, df, col2){
+   lapply(col1, function(i){
+     df2 <- df[col1 == i, col2]
+     df3 <- data.frame(cbind(sort(df2, decreasing = TRUE), rownames(data.table(sort(df2, decreasing = TRUE)))))
+     df3[ , 2]
+   })
+   }
> f1(df$Game.ID, df, c('MP'))[1:10]
[[1]]
 [1] 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
Levels: 1 10 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

[[2]]
 [1] 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
Levels: 1 10 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

[[3]]
 [1] 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13
Levels: 1 10 11 12 13 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

[[4]]
 [1] 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
Levels: 1 10 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

[[5]]
 [1] 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13
Levels: 1 10 11 12 13 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

[[6]]
 [1] 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13
Levels: 1 10 11 12 13 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

[[7]]
 [1] 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13
Levels: 1 10 11 12 13 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

[[8]]
 [1] 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13
Levels: 1 10 11 12 13 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

[[9]]
 [1] 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13
Levels: 1 10 11 12 13 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

[[10]]
 [1] 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
Levels: 1 10 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

But how can I extract only the row that corresponds to each observation? So, for example, the ranks I would like to extract from the first 10 observations of `df` are 5, 4, 11, 3, 8, 11, 1, 6, 9, and 8 respectively.

I've tried using the variable in the function in `lapply()`, `i`, to reference the row being operated on; but, it seems to only reference the `df$Game.ID` to which it's been assigned, not its entire row.

```
> f1 <- function(col1, df, col2){
+   col4 <- lapply(col1, function(i){
+     df2 <- df[col1 == i, col2]
+     df3 <- data.frame(cbind(sort(df2, decreasing = TRUE), rownames(data.table(sort(df2, decreasing = TRUE)))))
+     df3[i, 2]
+   })
+   }
> f1(df$Game.ID, df, c('MP'))[1:10]
[[1]]
[1] 7
Levels: 1 10 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

[[2]]
[1] 7
Levels: 1 10 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

[[3]]
[1] 6
Levels: 1 10 11 12 13 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

[[4]]
[1] 7
Levels: 1 10 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

[[5]]
[1] 6
Levels: 1 10 11 12 13 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

[[6]]
[1] 6
Levels: 1 10 11 12 13 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

[[7]]
[1] 6
Levels: 1 10 11 12 13 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

[[8]]
[1] 6
Levels: 1 10 11 12 13 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

[[9]]
[1] 6
Levels: 1 10 11 12 13 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

[[10]]
[1] 7
Levels: 1 10 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

> f1 <- function(col1, df, col2){
+   col4 <- lapply(col1, function(i){
+     df2 <- df[col1 == i, col2]
+     df3 <- data.frame(cbind(sort(df2, decreasing = TRUE), rownames(data.table(sort(df2, decreasing = TRUE)))))
+     df3[df3$X1 == df[col1 == i, col2], 2]
+   })
+   }
> f1(df$Game.ID, df, c('MP'))[1:10]
[[1]]
[1] 3
Levels: 1 10 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

[[2]]
[1] 3
Levels: 1 10 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

[[3]]
factor(0)
Levels: 1 10 11 12 13 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

[[4]]
[1] 3
Levels: 1 10 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

[[5]]
factor(0)
Levels: 1 10 11 12 13 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

[[6]]
factor(0)
Levels: 1 10 11 12 13 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

[[7]]
factor(0)
Levels: 1 10 11 12 13 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

[[8]]
factor(0)
Levels: 1 10 11 12 13 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

[[9]]
factor(0)
Levels: 1 10 11 12 13 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

[[10]]
[1] 3
Levels: 1 10 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

> f1 <- function(col1, df, col2){
+   col4 <- lapply(col1, function(i){
+     df2 <- df[col1 == i, col2]
+     df3 <- data.frame(cbind(sort(df2, decreasing = TRUE), rownames(data.table(sort(df2, decreasing = TRUE)))))
+     df3[df3$X1 == df[i, col2], 2]
+   })
+   }
> f1(df$Game.ID, df, c('MP'))[1:10]
[[1]]
factor(0)
Levels: 1 10 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

[[2]]
factor(0)
Levels: 1 10 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

[[3]]
[1] 11 12 13
Levels: 1 10 11 12 13 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

[[4]]
factor(0)
Levels: 1 10 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

[[5]]
[1] 11 12 13
Levels: 1 10 11 12 13 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

[[6]]
[1] 11 12 13
Levels: 1 10 11 12 13 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

[[7]]
[1] 11 12 13
Levels: 1 10 11 12 13 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

[[8]]
[1] 11 12 13
Levels: 1 10 11 12 13 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

[[9]]
[1] 11 12 13
Levels: 1 10 11 12 13 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

[[10]]
factor(0)
Levels: 1 10 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

How do I reference another column in the same row being operated on by `lapply()`?

Comment: I think you should edit your question and make it more minimal.

Comment: Two cases is as minimal as I can get. To refine my sample data set to one level of `df$Game.ID`, with no variation, would defeat the purpose of my asking how to select for it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that we need the `index` of the `sort`ed values, use the `index.return = TRUE` in `sort`.

```
f1 <- function(col1, df, col2){
 lapply(col1, function(i){
  df2 <- df[col1 == i, col2]
   sort(df2, decreasing = TRUE, index.return = TRUE)

 })
 }
f1(df$Game.ID, df, 'MP')[1:2]
```

There are duplicate elements in 'Game.ID'.  So, it may be better to pass `unique` elements into the function or change within the function

```
f1(unique(df$Game.ID), df, 'MP')[1:2]
```

As it is a `factor`, more efficient would be to pass the `levels`

```
res <- f1(levels(df$Game.ID), df, 'MP')
names(res) <- levels(df$Game.ID)
res[1:2]
#$`2018-02-01 * DEN`
#$`2018-02-01 * DEN`$x
#[1] 33 29  4

#$`2018-02-01 * DEN`$ix
#[1] 3 1 2


#$`2018-02-01 * DET`
#$`2018-02-01 * DET`$x
#[1] 39 36 32

#$`2018-02-01 * DET`$ix
#[1] 3 2 1
```

In the output, `ix` is the index and 'x' is the sorted value

Answer (score 1):

You can try this function to avoid having to compute the same ranking per `Game.ID` multiple times. The new column `rn` shows the original row number of the entry

```
f2 <- function(df) {
    require(dplyr)
    temp <- dplyr::mutate(df, rn = row_number())
    dplyr::arrange(temp, Game.ID, desc(MP)) %>%
        split(., .$Game.ID, drop=TRUE)  
}
f2(df)

# $`2018-02-01 * MIN`
   # MP Player.ID          Game.ID rn
# 1  40 butleji01 2018-02-01 * MIN  7
# 2  33 gibsota01 2018-02-01 * MIN 14
# 3  33 townska01 2018-02-01 * MIN 21
# 4  30 wiggian01 2018-02-01 * MIN 23
# 5  28 teaguje01 2018-02-01 * MIN 20
# 6  17 crawfja01 2018-02-01 * MIN  8
# 7  17 jonesty01 2018-02-01 * MIN 17
# 8  14 bjeline01 2018-02-01 * MIN  5
# 9  13 dienggo01 2018-02-01 * MIN  9
# 10  6 georgma01 2018-02-01 * MIN 13
# 11  3 aldrico01 2018-02-01 * MIN  3
# 12  3 brookaa01 2018-02-01 * MIN  6
# 13  3 muhamsh01 2018-02-01 * MIN 18

# $`2018-02-01 * OKC`
   # MP Player.ID          Game.ID rn
# 14 39 westbru01 2018-02-01 * OKC 22
# 15 36 georgpa01 2018-02-01 * OKC 12
# 16 34 anthoca01 2018-02-01 * OKC  4
# 17 32 adamsst01 2018-02-01 * OKC  2
# 18 29 abrinal01 2018-02-01 * OKC  1
# 19 25 grantje01 2018-02-01 * OKC 15
# 20 15 pattepa01 2018-02-01 * OKC 19
# 21 14 feltora01 2018-02-01 * OKC 10
# 22 12 huestjo01 2018-02-01 * OKC 16
# 23  4 fergute01 2018-02-01 * OKC 11
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. I was able to call the appropriate rank for each observation using `library(data.table)`.

```
> setDT(df)
> df[, Depth.Chart := rank(-MP), by = Game.ID]
> df
    MP Player.ID          Game.ID Depth.Chart
 1: 29 abrinal01 2018-02-01 * OKC         5.0
 2: 32 adamsst01 2018-02-01 * OKC         4.0
 3:  3 aldrico01 2018-02-01 * MIN        12.0
 4: 34 anthoca01 2018-02-01 * OKC         3.0
 5: 14 bjeline01 2018-02-01 * MIN         8.0
 6:  3 brookaa01 2018-02-01 * MIN        12.0
 7: 40 butleji01 2018-02-01 * MIN         1.0
 8: 17 crawfja01 2018-02-01 * MIN         6.5
 9: 13 dienggo01 2018-02-01 * MIN         9.0
10: 14 feltora01 2018-02-01 * OKC         8.0
11:  4 fergute01 2018-02-01 * OKC        10.0
12: 36 georgpa01 2018-02-01 * OKC         2.0
13:  6 georgma01 2018-02-01 * MIN        10.0
14: 33 gibsota01 2018-02-01 * MIN         2.5
15: 25 grantje01 2018-02-01 * OKC         6.0
16: 12 huestjo01 2018-02-01 * OKC         9.0
17: 17 jonesty01 2018-02-01 * MIN         6.5
18:  3 muhamsh01 2018-02-01 * MIN        12.0
19: 15 pattepa01 2018-02-01 * OKC         7.0
20: 28 teaguje01 2018-02-01 * MIN         5.0
21: 33 townska01 2018-02-01 * MIN         2.5
22: 39 westbru01 2018-02-01 * OKC         1.0
23: 30 wiggian01 2018-02-01 * MIN         4.0
    MP Player.ID          Game.ID Depth.Chart
```